# Design best practice - best way to handle user selection

Tags: android

I'm an experienced developer (WPF) moving over to Android development.  My question: an app I am developing allows the user to browse their local storage (such as SDCARD) and select a file. Now, should I simply create a new Activity (after the user has made a selection) to handle what I want to have the app do with that chosen file, -or- is the better approach to pass the path/name of the selected file back to the main Activity and let IT launch the next Activity?

In other words, is the better practice to have the main Activity launch other (support) activities, or is it perfectly ok and normal to have one activity chain to another and on and on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet:  Use separate activities because that is how Android was designed to handle different UI actions.

From Android Dev Documentation:

> Activities in the system are managed as an activity stack. When a new
>   activity is started, it is placed on the top of the stack and becomes
>   the running activity -- the previous activity always remains below it
>   in the stack, and will not come to the foreground again until the new
>   activity exits.

An activity has essentially four states:

- If an activity in the foreground of the screen (at the top of the
  stack), it is active or running.
- If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your
  activity), it is paused. A paused activity is completely alive (it
  maintains all state and member information and remains attached to
  the window manager), but can be killed by the system in extreme low
  memory situations.
- If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped. It still retains all state and member information, however,
  it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it
  will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.
- If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing
  its process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be
  completely restarted and restored to its previous state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's completely ok that there is a chain of Activities. Mostly because of navigation: if user selects file, worked with it and then pressed "back" button, then he'll see the **previous** opened activity (and then, maybe, he'll select another file). In other way it'll be a not predictable behaviour to users.